# Ajax call returns entire page rather than just the echo value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, echo

I am making an ajax call to a .php page where I am making a query to the database. However, when I echo a value from the .php page, the entire html file is returned rather than just the numerical value I need.

This is my ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#valuebutton").click(function()
    {
        var id1=$('.player1').val();
        $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatevaluebox.php",
        data: ({g1: id1}),
        cache: false,
        success: function(value)
        {
            //alert(value);
            $('#valuebox').val(value);
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the php page updatevaluebox.php:

```
<?php
    require("connect_db.php");
    $q="SELECT price FROM playerlist where id=".$_POST['g1'];
    $r=mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
    $price=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_NUM);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    echo $price[0];
?>
```

Both files are in the same directory.

I have checked other answers to this question on stackoverflow but none seem to work.

The output I am getting from the alert statement looks like:

```
<html>

<head><title>

</title></head>

<body>

</body>

</html>5.5
```

The 5.5 at the end is the only value I need!

I have set the ajax dataType to text but even that doesn't help.

Comment: What is the other text you are getting beforehand?

Comment: <html>

    <head><title>

    </title></head>

    <body>

    </body>

    </html>5.5

I am getting this entire thing rather than just 5.5!

Comment: How about this... does your connect_db.php file have any HTML code in it?  If it does then you should eliminate it...

Comment: It does yes!

<html>

<head><title>

</title></head>

<body>
<?php
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','********','********','ff') OR die(mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset($dbc,'utf-8');
?>
</body>
</html>

Do you suggest removing it?

Comment: That solved the problem my friend! I removed the html code and it works fine now! Thanks a million brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep!  You need to remove any HTML in the connect_db.php file.  I recommend storing a variable in that file checking if your connection was successful.  For example:

**connect_db.php**

```
$isConnected = false;
$dbError = "";
if ($dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','*****','*****','ff') {
    $isConnected = true;
} else {
    $dbError = mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

**other files**

```
require("connect_db.php");

if($isConnected) {
    //DO ALL YO STUFF!!
} else {
    //HANDLE THE ERROR AS YOU LIKE, LIKE PRINTING IT OUT
    echo $dbError;
}
```

Doing this will allow you to handle the DB logic in your files if it fails to connect so you may handle failed connections gracefully.

Comment: @kirkbackus. I am falling into the same issue. I have PHP/HTML in the same .php file, as some of the data is read from the html form and are passed as variable to the php/mysql query. Hence, I am trying to include in a single file. However, when I make ajax calls, I get the complete html ouput without the json data requested. Can you suggest alternative ?