# Send data from Javascript to PHP and use PHP's response as variable in JS

Tags: php, javascript

I have checked around, but can't seem to figure out how this is done.
I would like to send form data to PHP to have it processed and inserted into a database (this is working).

Then I would like to send a variable ($selected_moid) back from PHP to a JavaScript function (the same one if possible) so that it can be used again.

```
function submit_data() {
    "use strict";
    $.post('insert.php', $('#formName').formSerialize());
    $.get('add_host.cgi?moid='.$selected_moid.');
}
```

Here is my latest attempt, but still getting errors:

**PHP:**

```
$get_moid = "
    SELECT ID FROM nagios.view_all_monitored_objects
    WHERE CoID='$company'
    AND MoTypeID='$type'
    AND MoName='$name'
    AND DNS='$name.$selected_shortname.mon'
    AND IP='$ip'
    ";
while($MonitoredObjectID = mysql_fetch_row($get_moid)){
    //Sets MonitoredObjectID for added/edited device.
    $Response = $MonitoredObjectID;
    if ($logon_choice = '1') {
        $Response = $Response'&'$logon_id;
        $Response = $Response'&'$logon_pwd;
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

**JS:**

```
function submit_data(action, formName) {
    "use strict";
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'library/plugins/' + action + '.php',
        data: $('#' + formName).serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            // PROCESS DATA HERE
            var resp = $.parseJSON(response);
            $.get('/nagios/cgi-bin/add_host.cgi', {moid: resp });
            alert('success!');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            //PROCESS HERE FOR FAILURE
            alert('failure 'response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752001/ajax-call-returns-entire-page-rather-than-just-the-echo-value it is called ajax request

Comment: There's no need for your `$.get()` here - you can return the variable as a response from your `$.post()` and handle it in a callback function. Look at the [jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a callback function to get the returned value.

```
function submit_data(action, formName) {
    "use strict";
    $.post('insert.php', $('#' + formName).formSerialize(), function (selected_moid) {
        $.get('add_host.cgi', {moid: selected_moid });
    });
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, I'll try it.

Comment: I fixed it to use the `formName` parameter properly. I'm not sure how you intended `action` to be used.

Comment: I actually meant to take that out for simplicity's sake. The parameters were only used in the real JS.
For use on here, I didn't think it was needed to have them present.
I updated the OP with the more simplified example.

Comment: They don't affect the important part of the answer.

Comment: I thought I chose this one, but just saw that I never did. Sorry.
This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I am going out on a limb on this since your question is not 100% clear.  First of all, Javascript AJAX calls are asynchronous, meaning both the `$.get` and `$.post` will be call almost simultaneously.

If you are trying to get the response from one and using it in a second call, then you need to nest them in the success function.  Since you are using jQuery, take a look at their API to see the arguments your AJAX call can handle (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post('insert.php', $('#formName').formSerialize(),function(data){
    $.get('add_host.cgi?moid='+data);
});
```

In your PHP script, after you have updated the database and everything, just `echo` the data want.  Javascript will take the text and put it in the `data` variable in the success function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("ID OF THE SUBMIT BUTTON").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'FILE IN HERE FOR PROCESSING',
                data: $("ID HERE OF THE FORM").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                   // PROCESS DATA HERE

                },
                error: function(data) {
                   //PROCESS HERE FOR FAILURE
                }
            });
            return false; //This stops the Button from Actually Preforming
        });
```

Now for the Php

```
<?php
 start_session(); <-- This will make it share the same Session Princables
 //error check and soforth use $_POST[] to get everything
$Response = array('success'=>true, 'VAR'=>'DATA'); <--- Success 
$Response = array('success'=>false, 'VAR'=>'DATA'); <--- fails
  echo json_encode($Response);
?>
```

I forgot to Mention, this is using JavaScript/jQuery, and ajax to do this.

Example of this as a Function

```
    Var Form_Data = THIS IS THE DATA OF THE FORM;
function YOUR FUNCTION HERE(VARS HERE) {
                   $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'FILE IN HERE FOR PROCESSING',
                        data:Form_Data.serialize(),
                        success: function(data) {
                           // PROCESS DATA HERE

                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                           //PROCESS HERE FOR FAILURE
                        }
                    });
    }
```

Now you could use this as the Button Click which would also function :3

Comment: Can an AJAX function like this be stored in the format I have in the OP?
It is called from more than one place would like to still use the function submit_data(); format.

Comment: Attempted this, but getting an error in console:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token P jquery-latest.js:550
jQuery.extend.parseJSON jquery-latest.js:550
$.ajax.success javascript.js:176
fire jquery-latest.js:3048
self.fireWith jquery-latest.js:3160
done jquery-latest.js:8235
callback